# nuget contentFiles: is a binary file instead of a text file

Tags: nuget

Adding a binary file to the "contentFiles" of my nuget package leads to a build error in my C# project.

```
CSC : error CS2015: '...\0.0.14\contentFiles\any\any\archive.7z' is a binary file instead of a text file [...]
```

My goal is to have this binary file in my build output folder after `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`.

details:

```
# .nuspec
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        ...
        
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="archive.7z" flatten="true" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
        </contentFiles>
        
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="content/archive.7z" target="contentFiles\any\any" />
    </files>
</package>
```

```
# folder structure
├───content
│   └───archive.7z
└───.nuspec
```

```
# .csproj file
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="my-nuget-package-name" Version="0.0.14" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If you read [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/) it seems the default action is to compile a content file if no other build action is specified. You might want to specify a build action of None or EmbeddedResource.

Comment: changing the 'buildAction' to EmbeddedResource did not have an effect, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to add the path to contentFiles "any/any/archive.7z"

```
<files include="any/any/archive.7z" flatten="true" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
```

so the correct .nuspec file should look like this:

```
# .nuspec
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        ...
        
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="any/any/archive.7z" flatten="true" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
        </contentFiles>
        
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="content/archive.7z" target="contentFiles\any\any" />
    </files>
</package>
```